# Ошибка SQLConnection: near "index": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, lazarus

Пишу программу на Лазарусе. Бд на языке SQLite. При нажатии кнопки хочу обновить данные в бд и делаю следующее:

```
fAuto.SQLQ.Close;
fAuto.SQLQ.SQL.Clear;
fAuto.SQLQ.SQL.Text := 'update books set ISBN=:ISBN, book_name=:BN, author=:A, original_name=:ON, original_language=:OL, publisher_name=:PN, translator=:T, issue_year=:IY, page_count=:PC, book_count=:BC, book_price=:BP, only_for_reading_room=:OFRR, comment=:C where index=:I';
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('ISBN').AsString := eISBN.Text;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('BN').AsString := eBookName.Text;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('A').AsString := eAuthor.Text;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('ON').AsString := eOriginalName.Text;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('OL').AsString := eOriginalLanguage.Text;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('PN').AsString := ePublisherName.Text;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('T').AsString := eTranslator.Text;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('IY').AsString := eIssueYear.Text;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('PC').AsInteger := ePageCount.Value;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('BC').AsInteger := eBookCount.Value;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('BP').AsString := eBookPrice.Text;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('OFRR').AsBoolean := eOFRR.Checked;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('C').AsString := eComment.Lines.Text;
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('I').AsInteger := strtoint(eIndex.Text);
fAuto.SQLQ.ExecSQL;
fAuto.SQLTransaction.Commit;
fAuto.SQLQ.Close;
```

После нажатия на кнопку программа останавливается на fAuto.SQLQ.ExecSQL и выдает ошибку

> SQLConnection: near "index": syntax error

Структура таблицы books:
[image: Структура таблицы]

Comment: так подключиться надо к базе данных прежде чем выполнять запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ:

В ходе совместных исследований выяснилось, что проблема заключается в  `index` и это слово является [ключевым](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) По этой причине запрос не мог правильно интерпретировать часть `where index=xxx` так как это слово для работы с индексацией таблиц (`CREATE INDEX`, `DROP INDEX`). Лучше всего в этом случае использовать имя `id` так как оно фактически является стандартом для обозначения индексных полей.

Первоначальные догадки:

У Вас ошибка в формировании запроса. По всей вероятности в `eIndex.Text` пусто или не число, это возможная ошибка рядом с `index` - о чем и написано в сообщении:

> `SQLConnection: near "index": syntax error`

и запрос выглядит как: `"... where index="` попробуйте вставить туда какое-то значение имеющегося индекса, для проверки.

```
fAuto.SQLQ.ParamByName('I').AsInteger := strtoint(eIndex.Text);
```

Comment: Проверил: все равно выдавал ошибку. Решил удалить столбец index и первичным ключом сделал ISBN. Все заработало. Может, index не искался потому что я ему автоинкремент ставил, хотя вроде не должно

Comment: Инкремент не должен был влиять, он влияет только на добавление записей, но в любом случае какая-то ошибка с `index` происходила, нужно было бы посмотреть финальный SQL запрос

Comment: Да, я заново добавил index, но уже без инкремента. Ошибка все равно возникала. Тогда я переименовал столбец из index в ind и заработало

Comment: Получается `index` зарезервированное слово не знал)

Comment: Да, тоже не знал. Все искал, где ошибка, а оказывается просто ключевое слово использовал :)

Comment: [тут кстати список](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html), а я никогда с этим не сталкивался так как использовал `id`